# HTML Using select form to change input selection (Possibly using JQuery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it's possible that when you select a category that the option you chose will determine the text boxes that follows it. So in the example I gave below if someone selects handbags they get asked handbag type and vice versa for shoes and heels.

I know that this may require JQuery but i'm not very proficient at it so the solutions I found only changed the data of a single box. If what i'm hoping to achieve can be done please let me know.

Thank you! :)

```
Category:
<select name="category" form="sku">
    <option value="Handbags">Handbags</option>
    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
</select>

<p>Handbag Type:</p>
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Tote"><br />

<p>Handbag Size:</p>
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Large"><br />

<p>Shoes Type:</p>
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Heel"><br />

<p>Heel height:</p>
<input type="text" name="type" placeholder='Example: 4.5"'><br />
```

Comment: yes very possible show what you tried so far :)

Comment: It'd make your life easier if you wrapped the `<p><input>` groups in a wrapper element like a `<div>` and gave each div an ID to reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your HTML slightly to group the parts that are for handbags and shoes respectively like so:

```
Category:
<select name="category" form="sku" id=myselect>
    <option value="Handbags">Handbags</option>
    <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
</select>

<div class='Handbags input-sections'>
    <p>Handbag Type:</p>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Tote"><br />

    <p>Handbag Size:</p>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Large"><br />
</div>

<div class='Shoes input-sections'>

    <p>Shoes Type:</p>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder="Example: Heel"><br />

    <p>Heel height:</p>
    <input type="text" name="type" placeholder='Example: 4.5"'><br />
</div>
```

and then have just normal javascript to show and hide the sections depending on what was selected.

For example:

```
var select = document.getElementById('myselect');
select.onchange=function(){
    // Hide all sections
    var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('input-sections');
    for(var i=0;i<sections.length;i++)
        sections[i].style.display='none';

    // Show the section that was chosen
    document.getElementsByClassName(this.value)[0].style.display='block';
}
```